# Virtual desktop for Windows that allow window assignment programatically

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

Does anyone know a virtual desktop software for Windows that allow me to start a program from the command line, and assign it to a specific desktop. I.e I dont want to start it in the current desktop then manually drag it to the next one.

Thanks,

Comment: Which virtual desktop software are you using.

Comment: I tried Virtual Desktop Assist and goScreen but could not find that feature. I can switch to another one.

Answer (score 2):

Starting a program from the command line is o.s. specific. It has nothing to do with **Virtual** Desktops.

There is one tool I know of, named [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/). It is very useful for me. Consider a look at.

Comment: Your first statement does not make sense. The question asks how to start a program from the command line and assign it to a specific workspace/virtual desktop, bypassing manual interaction with the GUI.

Comment: The question is about starting a program from command line to assign a specific virtual desktop. That assignment needs a parameter in "run" command. That is why i made my first statement.

Comment: or if the virtual desktop program provide the utility to start a program and automatically assign it to one of the available desktops :)

Comment: I just tried VirtualWin and it is cool. It allows setting up rule to move program to a certain desktop as they start up. Thanks a bunch.